# Inside jquery function can i call angular 5 function

Tags: angular

I am trying to call onPaymentStatus() function inside the jQuery function. But i am unable use 'this' scope

```
this.braintree.client.create({
  authorization: 'client_token'},
  (err, client) => {
      client.request({
        endpoint: 'payment_methods/credit_cards',
        method: 'post',
        data: data
      }, function (requestErr, response) {

       if (requestErr) { throw new Error(requestErr); }
       console.log('Got nonce:', response.creditCards[0].nonce);
       this.onPaymentStatus(response.creditCards[0].nonce); //
    });
});

onPaymentStatus (nonce) {
  console.log(nonce);
}
```

I got error ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'onPaymentStatus' of null

Comment: Angular5 is written in typescript. Anyways after compilation it gets converted into Javascript by the WebPack. So technically you can call it on while on runtime. But my question will be WHY? why can't you write the entire thing in angualr? Do some research

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to make a reference to the component outside the jQuery function as the meaning of `this` changes within it

```
const component = this;
```

Then call

```
component.onPaymentStatus()
```

Comment: really helpful.

Comment: Wow this is really helpful! Thanks a ton, mate!